# Space between Each Tableviewrow Titanium Alloy

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, tableview, titanium-alloy

[image]

How to get space between TableViewRow has show in above image.

Window.js

```
for(var i=0;i < election.length ;i++){
//  
    tblRow_Election[i] = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
        height:(Ti.Platform.osname == 'ipad')?'280':'140',
        width:Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth,
        left:(Ti.Platform.osname == 'ipad')?'20':'10',
        right:(Ti.Platform.osname == 'ipad')?'20':'10',
        color:'red',
        touchEnabled: true, 
        borderRadius:'4',
        borderWidth:'1',
        borderColor:'green',

    }); 

        data.push(tblRow_Election[i]);
}

    $.tbl_ElectionList.data = data;
```

Window.tss

```
"#tbl_ElectionList":{

    top:'40',
    height:'auto',
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    left:'10',
    right:'10', 
    style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED,
    borderColor:'green',
    separatorInsets: {
      left:0,
      right:0,
  },
}
```

Window.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="ElectionWin" class="ElectionWindow" >
        <View class="container" id = "view_Election" backgroundColor="white">
            <TableView id="tbl_ElectionList">
            </TableView>    
    </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Unable to get gap between each row .  Can any one advice me how to achieve the gap between each tableviewRow.

@All Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Armand Its related to IOS! but using cross platform titanium studio and javascript.

Comment: in that case I'm sorry... Can you re set the TAG, or do I need to do it ?

Comment: No problem, I will edit and re-tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to set the [separator style to none](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-property-separatorStyle), so that you can define gaps yourself, you can set this in the table' tss, I would also not use the grouped style as this further constrains your styling:

```
"#tbl_ElectionList":{
    top:'40',
    height:Ti.UI.SIZE,
    left:'10',
    right:'10', 
    separatorStyle : Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewSeparatorStyle.NONE,
    borderColor:'green'
}
```

Try adding rows that way and you should see the gaps

```
var containerrow = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
    height:(Ti.Platform.osname == 'ipad')?'280':'140',
    width: Ti.UI.FILL
}); 

// This innerView will be set in the middle of the row
// It will hold your main row content
// We make it smaller than the row to give padding
var innerView = Ti.UI.createView({
    width : '80%',
    height : '80%',
    color:'red',
    borderRadius:4,
    borderWidth:1,
    borderColor:'green'
 });
 containerrow.add(innerView);
 // Add to the table data
 data.push(containerrow);
```

Then of course set the data as you did before.